# Logging-class in PHP (best performance)

Tags: php

I've taken over a codebase, that implemented a logging-class in a quite extensive way.

### How they did it

**Logger class**

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class customLogger {
  public $log;

  public function __construct( $name = 'CUSTOMLOGGER', $ignore_stdout = false ){
    $logger_location = get_template_directory() . "/custom/log/dest/mylog.log";
    $formatter       = new LineFormatter( null, null, true, true );
    $this->log       = new Logger( $name );

    $log_out = new StreamHandler( $logger_location, Logger::INFO );
    $log_out->setFormatter( $formatter );
    $this->log->pushHandler( $log_out );

    if( ! $ignore_stdout ){
      $std_out = new StreamHandler( "php://stdout", Logger::INFO );
      $std_out->setFormatter( $formatter );
      $this->log->pushHandler( $std_out );
    }
  }

  /**
   * get_logger
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function get_logger(){
    return $this->log;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class someOtherClass {
  protected static $log;

  protected static function setup_logger(){
    $logger    = new customLogger();
    self::$log = $logger->get_logger();

    return self::$log;
  }
  
  public function runImport(){
    self::setup_logger();
    self::$log->info('import: Begin...');
    
    // Do some stuff

    self::$log->info('import: Begin...');
  }
}
```

In my opinion it just seems like quite a lot of overhead, to simply write to a file. I assume that it has something to do with performance. So it only has to write to the file a single time and not several.

### The lazy way

It could also just be implemented with a public static function, like this:

```
class logClass {

  public static function logSomething( $log ){
    $filename = '/custom/log/dest/mylog.log';
    file_put_contents( $filename, $log, FILE_APPEND );
  }
}


class someOtherClass {

  public function runImport(){
    logClass::logSomething('import: Begin...' );
    // Do some stuff
    logClass::logSomething('import: Finished...' );
  }
}
```

---

### The question

How do I compare the performance of these two ways of logging stuff in the code, to see how much better the first one is?

**Bonus-question:** If you have a better way to implement a logger-function, then I'm all ears. :-)

Comment: My guess is that they _didn’t_ do this for performance reasons. Monolog is a very common logging library that allows you to log in a consistent fashion to many different places, including stdout, which your version doesn’t. My guess is that this code is or was part of something that does/did more, or was planned to do more, or that they just lifted this from another project since they knew it worked. For that specific use-case, I don’t think there’s really any performance worth measuring.

Answer (score 0):

as @Chris Haas correctly said, the first way is not a performance-cared-based solution, it could have been written based on a lot of reasons :

- They might intend to create a new library at another time.
- they might want to switch to another library rather than monolog later
- They might force posterior new logger to keep psr3 conventions (with complete their custom logger later). and etc.

but what they think and what they planned to do is not the purpose of your question, so let us pass them and focus on yours.

your solution can achieve higher performance in some cases, it's not deniable, so why we must use standard accepted log libraries just like monolog?

- in case of the massive amount of logging processing.
- for keeping psr3 rules and implementing its interfaces.
- organize the logs with channel names and flags.
- have variant choices to save logs into a local file on disk to log to a remote database over a network.
- Thread safety in logging simultaneously from multiple different threads.
- Automatic tagging of logs entries with a timestamp and any other relevant information.
- accessing a variety of provided APIs to work with databases just like influx/mongo/Redis/elastic and ... with different formats and special handles.
- sending notifications and emails
- etc

These are just some advantages of using standard log libraries, obviously, there are many other reasons that I can't mention now.

keep that in mind: all standard libraries eventually do something just like you do with file put content function, but they provide variably of abilities for us before it.

back to your question: if you want to test the performance, you can use some network tools created for purposes just like doing load test and/or stress test. you can also do it by some applications just like selenium with creating ajax request to two functions that they implement 2 logging approach and get the results.